# ASP.net MVC 4 Razor ShortDateTime field issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to show my date like this `dd/mm/yyyy` instead of `date+ time`
this's my code

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OFFRE_DATE, "Date d'offre")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OFFRE_DATE, new { @Value = Model.OFFRE_DATE.Value.ToString("ddmm/yyyy"), @class="datepicker" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OFFRE_DATE)
    </div>
```

Also I have tried `(model => model.OFFRE_DATE.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` and `(model => model.OFFRE_DATE.Value.ToShortDateString` but none of them worked.

```
I'm using EF dataModel and this's `offre.cs`
    public partial class OFFRE
    {
        public short OFFRE_ID { get; set; }
        public short REGION_ID { get; set; }
        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> OFFRE_DATE { get; set; }

        public virtual REGION REGION { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sloved my problem :

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> OFFRE_DATE { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the datetime format like this:

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"] 
public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; }

In the view:

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyDate)

If you are using validation then you have to set the culture and uiculture for a correct validation. The validation is look at the culture.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bz9tc508(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: But I was helpful it gave me an idea

Comment: do you use view models?

Comment: Ok, do you define the display-format in the view-model?`

Answer (score 0):

Use [ToShortDateTimeString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx):

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OFFRE_DATE, "Date d'offre")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OFFRE_DATE, new { @Value = Model.OFFRE_DATE.Value.ToShortDateTimeString(), @class="datepicker" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OFFRE_DATE)
    </div>
```

Comment: I have Tried this and it show me this error `'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'ToShortDateTimeString' and no extension method 'ToShortDateTimeString' accepting a first argument of type 'System.DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use the `ToString()` method of the DateTime type :

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Would return "24/04/2014" (If you run it today of course ^_^).

I personnally like this cause it's not depending on the regional settings of the server, which others could consider a disadvantage though. It also offers a lot of flexibility in the output string.

Comment: I want the `Offre_Date` to be showed not Datetime.now and `@Value = Model.OFFRE_DATE.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` doesn't slove my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `OFFRE_DATE` variable to `DateTime` and then apply the `ToString()` to get the datetime string value.

Try This:

```
 @Value = ((DateTime) Model.OFFRE_DATE.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```